# External monitor breaks display configuration randomly

Tags: unity, 16.04, multiple-monitors, display

If I disconnect my laptop, use it for a while, then go to hook it back up to the external monitor via HDMI, the display completely freaks out.  The external monitor doesn't show up at all, the windows on the laptop monitor flicker and go all over the place.

However, most of the time, if I disconnect the HDMI cable, wait a couple minutes, and plug it back in, it works just fine.  Other times, I need to actually end my session before plugging in the monitor again.  Makes my Laptop much less practical.

Any ideas on what could be causing this or how to debug?  I'm new to Unity, I've been using KDE for a while.

Running Ubuntu 16.04.1, Intel® HD Graphics 520 (i5-6200u), External Monitor is HP 25es connected via HDMI.